# How to catch a count ports on Cisco Nexus Devices using tcl/expect?

Tags: tcl, expect, cisco

I wrote a script to catch a count of connected ports on Cisco Nexus devices as below:

Command Cisco:

```
example01#sh interface status | i connected | exclude Po | exclude Lo|count
13
example01#
```

Script Part:

```
send "sh interface status \| i connected \| exclude Po \| exclude Lo \| count\r"
expect -re {([0-9]+)}
set COUNT "$expect_out(0,string)"
puts "$COUNT\r"
```

The problem is the hostname of device have numbers too, like 01. When I save the ouput, what I see is just "01", and not the correct output that I expect (this case will be 13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
send "sh interface status \| i connected \| exclude Po \| exclude Lo \| count\r"
expect -re {([0-9]+)\r\n}
set COUNT "$expect_out(0,string)"
puts "$COUNT\r"
```

Now, the output is correct, because I did a newline with `\r\n`.

Comment: You might also be able to put a `^` at the beginning of that regular expression — `{^([0-9]+)\r\n}` — to constrain the possibilities even more.